# to get pid of command executed by system api call

Tags: c, linux, posix

I'm using system api in linux to achieve shell command operations. Sometimes while executing the command, a system call gets blocked and never returns. So if I know the process id of command which got executed, I will kill that process and call system api again.

eg:

```
system("ftpget -u<> -p<> ip remote-file local-file");
```

sometimes `ftpget` blocks and the system call never returns. So I don't want system call to be blocked indefinitely. Is there any solution other than killing `ftpget` process?
If not, then how do I get the process id of `ftpget`?

Comment: `system` is a convenience function around `fork`/`exec`.  If you want the pid, you'll have to sacrifice the convenience.

Comment: As above comment, but `posix_spawn` may prove a better option these days.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have concurrent ftpget instances running then you might forgo obtaining the pid by using a `system()` to killall, and kill the process by name.

```
system("killall ftpget");
```

You should consider using something like `execv()` however if you really need to kill an isolated instance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `system()` provides no mechanism to tell the caller the child processes' pid. You can use `fork()`/`exec()` to start the child process directly and keep the pid for your own use.

Note that the thus started process might spawn child processes by itself, that will again have pids you don't know.

Example (untested):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // child
        execlp("ftpget", "ftpget", "-u<>", "-p<>", "ip",
               "remote-file", "local-file", (char*)NULL);
        exit(-1); // this will only ever happen when exec fails
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {
        // parent
        std::cout << "pid of child process is " << pid << "\n";
        waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    }
    else {
        // error
    }
}
```

For reference:

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/system
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/fork
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid
- https://github.com/m-labs/uclibc-lm32/blob/master/libc/stdlib/system.c